# My audio player set to 'auto' plays on the wrong pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, paperclip, html5-audio

I have a small rails app where I've incorporated a player to play back some specific mp3 files.  What I want is to have this player played upon the page load. However what I've discovered is that every time I go to a different page (specifically one that is not supposed to have any audio) the player refreshes and starts playing the audio again. If anybody could take a quick look, I would appreciate it.

I have two views, the main view is a show page and in it i have a partial that goes straight to the player.

`.second-background-image
      = render partial: 'player'
      .container`

All I have in the partial is this

    `%audio#player{controls: 'controls', autoplay: 'true', loop: 'true' }
      %source{src: @cafe.mp3.url}`

I'm also using the paperclip gem to gather the mp3 information. Not sure if this part is useful to share, but below I have it.

`has_attached_file :mp3
      validates_attachment :mp3, :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] }, :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/] }`

I don't have any other CSS classes or anything affiliated with my code. I think it has something to do with me setting the `autoplay to true` but i didn't think that would cause a problem on every single page.

Would anybody know what i could do about this?

Comment: could you share the structure of your pages inside the folders? and on which page do you have this code?

Comment: Alright @amrrbakry just did.  I shared the remaining information i think should be useful here.